# saw respective view controllers on selecting the row in tabelview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to display different ViewController when I select the respective row in tableView. But I'm unable to fix it as it is showing Random ViewControllers after selecting the respective row for that Controller I checked all the identifiers for ViewControllers according but it is still displaying in a wrong way
Here is the code I have written :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch(indexPath.row) {
        case 0 : 
            let v1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass1") as! ViewControllerngodetails
            navigationController?.pushViewController(v1, animated: true)
            break

        case 1 : 
            let v2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass2") as! ViewController2Reg
            navigationController?.pushViewController(v2, animated: true)
            break

        case 2 : 
            let v3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass3") as! ViewController3FCRA
            navigationController?.pushViewController(v3, animated: true)        
            break

        case 3 : 
            let v4 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass4") as! ViewController4SecIssue
            navigationController?.pushViewController(v4, animated: true)
            break

        case 4 : 
            let v5 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass5") as! ViewController5contactdet
            navigationController?.pushViewController(v5, animated: true)
            break

        case 5 : 
            let v6 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass6") as! ViewController6bnkdetails
            navigationController?.pushViewController(v6, animated: true)
            break

       default: 
            break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never deselect the row. Maybe you have enabled multiple selection for your table view and it keeps the previous selection? Try putting this before the switch inside the `didSelectRowAt` method:

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

EDIT: I just saw you use the delegate method `didDeselectRowAt` and you should use `didSelectRowAt`. That's probably your problem right there. Once you changed it the `didSelectRowAt` method should deselect the row before doing anything else anyway.

Comment: Nice  If you can, please mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed looks fine. The problem probably lies in the input parameter(indexPath).
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

(I recommend you use breakpoints to identify the code that causes the problem)

Answer (score 0):

FYI You can do with storing all VC identifiers in array and call in didSelect method also.

```
let arrIdentifiers = ["pass1","pass2","pass3","pass4","pass5","pass6"]
```

didSelect of tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: arrIdentifiers[indexPath.row])
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```